# Errors upgrading to new dev plan from shared database plan

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to upgrade my apps to the new dev plan, but get errors during the report step:

```
jseidel@EDP15:~/Dev/xxx$ heroku pgbackups:restore postgres://[xxx].amazonaws.com:[xxx]
Database on [xxx].amazonaws.com <---restore--- b001 (most recent)
SHARED_DATABASE
2012/08/08 06:16.20
23.2KB
! WARNING: Potentially Destructive Action
! This command will affect the app: xxx
! To proceed, type "xxx" or re-run this command with --confirm xxx
xxx
Pending... \
! An error occurred and your restore did not finish.
```

Thanks...jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the actual URL (postgresql://xxx...) when I should have been using the database ID (HREOKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY)